# How to left join using select form

Tags: postgresql

I'm tryng to use a join function in my SQL request.

I have two table :

**tbl_jsontesting**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | data                                                                                                                                                                               | name       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | {"complexProperties":[{"properties":{"key":"Registred","Value":"123456789"}},{"properties":{"key":"Urgency","Value":"Total"}},{"properties":{"key":"ImpactScope","Value":"All"}}]} | Some Text  |
| 2  | {"complexProperties":[{"properties":{"key":"Registred","Value":"123456788"}},{"properties":{"key":"Urgency","Value":"Total"}},{"properties":{"key":"ImpactScope","Value":"All"}}]} | Some Text2 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**tbl_registred**

```
----------------------
| id        | name   |
----------------------
| 123456789 | Source |
| 123456788 | Cars   |
----------------------
```

The id from the table **tbl_registred** is linked to the id contained in table **tbl_jsontesting** in the column data when key is set to **Registred**

My current query :

```
select (j -> 'properties' ->> 'Value') as "Registred", "registred_name"
from 
(
 select json_array_elements("data"::json -> 'complexProperties') as j, tbl_registred.name as "registred_name"
 from tbl_jsontesting
LEFT JOIN tbl_registred ON tbl_jsontesting.id = tbl_registred.id
) as arrj
where j -> 'properties' ->> 'key' = 'Registred';
```

Result :

```
------------------------------
| Registred | registred_name |
------------------------------
| 123456788 | null           |
| 123456789 | null           |
------------------------------
```

My expected output :

```
------------------------------
| Registred | registred_name |
------------------------------
| 123456788 | Cars           |
| 123456789 | Source         |
------------------------------
```

My fidle :
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Jvq4SXUpBvJsY7H3G13xm/1

Comment: tbl_registered is not used at all because there's no match in the join condition. If tbl_jsontesting.id fields matched the tbl_registred.id fields it would work but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: I need to use `j -> 'properties' ->> 'Value'` instead of `tbl_jsontesting.id`

Comment: This would be sooo much easier with a properly normalized data model. What if there are multiple array elements with `key = Registered`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the array elements into rows and then join on the `Value` property:

```
select rg.id, rg.name, jt.name
from tbl_jsontesting jt
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(jt.data::jsonb -> 'complexProperties')  as p(props)
   join tbl_registred rg 
     on rg.id::text = (p.props -> 'properties' ->> 'Value')
    and p.props -> 'properties' ->> 'key' = 'Registred'
;
```

Another option is to use a JSON path query to get the `Value` for a specific `key`

```
select rg.id, rg.name, jt.name
from tbl_jsontesting jt
   join tbl_registred rg 
     on rg.id::text = (jsonb_path_query_first(jt.data::jsonb, '$.complexProperties[*].properties ? (@.key == "Registred").Value') #>> '{}')
```

As there is no direct cast from `jsonb` to `text` we must use the somewhat ugly hack `#>> '{}'` to convert it to a text value.

Alternatively you can convert the `id` column to a JSON scalar in the join condition:

```
on to_jsonb(rg.id::text) = jsonb_path_query_first(jt.data::jsonb, '$.complexProperties[*].properties ? (@.key == "Registred").Value')
```

---

Note that `jsontesting.data` should be defined as `jsonb` to avoid the annoying and costly cast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Is there a way to show also the row which don't have the key `Registred` (null value or empty string)? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Jvq4SXUpBvJsY7H3G13xm/2

Answer (score 1):

In your data there is not match between `tbl_registred.id` and `tbl_jsontesting.id` so your JOIN give no result.

According to your data I guess you want to join `tbl_registred.id` with `tbl_jsontesting > complexProperties > properties > Value`  where the key is 'Registred'
This is a long path to find the desired object so I will decompose the Json

```
WITH fuly_decomposed_tbl_jsontesting as (
  SELECT * , (JsonSubComplexProp->>'key') as key, (JsonSubComplexProp->>'Value') as value
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
        (
            json_array_elements(
                (j.data::json->'complexProperties')::json
            )::json->'properties'
        )::json as JsonSubComplexProp
     FROM tbl_jsontesting j
  ) decomposed_tbl_jsontesting
)
SELECT fjson.id, fjson.data, fjson.name, fjson.key ,fjson.value, tr.id, tr.name
FROM fuly_decomposed_tbl_jsontesting fjson
LEFT JOIN tbl_registred tr on tr.id::text = fjson.value
WHERE key='Registred'
```

you probably can do shorter but this way work and with the explosion of the json you can do what you want

result in your fiddle :

```
| id  | data                                                                                                                                                                               | name       | key       | value     | id        | name   |
| --- | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ---------- | --------- | --------- | --------- | ------ |
| 1   | {"complexProperties":[{"properties":{"key":"Registred","Value":"123456789"}},{"properties":{"key":"Urgency","Value":"Total"}},{"properties":{"key":"ImpactScope","Value":"All"}}]} | Some Text  | Registred | 123456789 | 123456789 | Source |
| 2   | {"complexProperties":[{"properties":{"key":"Registred","Value":"123456788"}},{"properties":{"key":"Urgency","Value":"Total"}},{"properties":{"key":"ImpactScope","Value":"All"}}]} | Some Text2 | Registred | 123456788 | 123456788 | Cars   |
```